# How to convert string time format to date or time in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am facing issue while converting string time format i.e., 0h 0m 53s+695ms
to date or time
I have a duration field with this format and is of type string , I have to add the duration of all the records in the collection matching on certain condition.

But I am getting error like :
Failed to parse number '0h 0m 53s+695ms' in $convert with no onError value: Bad digit "h" while parsing 0h 0m 53s+695ms" (Note: if I specify onError than the result only get populates with error conditions)
and many more of such kind.

Any clue on how to convert this specific type to data?

Comment: What kind of output do you expect?

Comment: I have this field in all my records I want a total time for all the records i.e., combining/adding time field of all the records based on certain condition

Comment: If we can convert this mentioned format to timestamp as it's type is string, then i can calculate the total time

Comment: I cannot imagine any way to make it even worse! Anyway, is the interval **always** shorter than 24 hours?

Comment: Is it always **exactly** this format?

Comment: Yes it will be under 24hr and exactly this format only.

Comment: Examples:- 6h 10m 53s+695ms

Answer (score 0):

This aggregation pipeline will convert the string into number of seconds. These you can sum up:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $set: { t: { $first: { $regexFindAll: { input: "$t", regex: /^(\d+)h (\d+)m (\d+)s\+(\d+)ms$/ } } } } },
   {
      $set: {
         t: {
            $sum: [
               { $multiply: [{ $toInt: { $arrayElemAt: ["$t.captures", 0] } }, 60 * 60] },
               { $multiply: [{ $toInt: { $arrayElemAt: ["$t.captures", 1] } }, 60] },
               { $toInt: { $arrayElemAt: ["$t.captures", 2] } },
               { $divide: [{ $toInt: { $arrayElemAt: ["$t.captures", 2] } }, 1000] }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
])
```

The output you can format like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $set: { t: { $first: { $regexFindAll: { input: "$t", regex: /^(\d+)h (\d+)m (\d+)s\+(\d+)ms$/ } } } } },
   {
      $set: {
         t: {
            $sum: [
               { $multiply: [{ $toInt: { $arrayElemAt: ["$t.captures", 0] } }, 60 * 60] },
               { $multiply: [{ $toInt: { $arrayElemAt: ["$t.captures", 1] } }, 60] },
               { $toInt: { $arrayElemAt: ["$t.captures", 2] } },
               { $divide: [{ $toInt: { $arrayElemAt: ["$t.captures", 2] } }, 1000] }
            ]
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $set: {
         t: {
            $dateToString: {
               date: { $toDate: { $multiply: ["$t", 1000] } },
               format: "%H:%M:%S.%L"
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```

Comment: GIVING ERROR:"ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Unrecognized expression '$first'",
    "code" : 168,
    "codeName" : "InvalidPipelineOperator"
} : aggregate failed :

Comment: Replace it by `{ $arrayElemAt: [... , 0] }`